# Get currently open Attribute Window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, add-in

I have an AddIn (C# VS 2010) that depends on the selected items in the Attribute Window (This is the right-click on the Layer Attributes Table Window). When the user hits Start Editing I want to get a handle on the Currently open Attribute Window (or check if it is open) and automatically select the correct Layer. I know how to get the currently selected layer as shown below.

```
var puid = new UID {Value = "{E156D7E5-22AF-11D3-9F99-00C04F6BC78E}"};
IEnumLayer penumlayer = _mxDocument.ActiveView.FocusMap.get_Layers(puid, true);
penumlayer.Reset();
featureLayer = penumlayer.Next() as IFeatureLayer;
```

But I need to check if the Attribute Window is open and then I can auto select the Layer with some other code based on the DataSet Name.

I'm hoping that someone has a code snippet that will help me.

Comment: Did you try `ITableWindow3.ActiveTableWindow` ? http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/ARCOBJECTS-NET/COMPONENTHELP/index.html#/ITableWindow3_Interface/000v00000196000000/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will get you the layer or standalone table (IStandaloneTable) of the active table window:

```
var pTableWindow3 = new TableWindow() as ITableWindow3;
if (pTableWindow3.ActiveTableWindow == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("no table open");
} 
else 
{
    var pTableWindow2 = pTableWindow3.ActiveTableWindow as ITableWindow2;
    if (pTableWindow2.Layer != null)
    {
        var pLayer = pTableWindow2.Layer as ILayer;
    }
    else
    {
        var pStandaloneTable = pTableWindow2.StandaloneTable as IStandaloneTable;
    }
}
```

http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/ARCOBJECTS-NET/COMPONENTHELP/index.html#/ITableWindow2_Interface/000v0000018s000000/

http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/ARCOBJECTS-NET/COMPONENTHELP/index.html#/ITableWindow3_Interface/000v00000196000000/

Comment: Thanks Dan! Your code snippet was EXACTLY what I needed. Beautiful to see my code now able to find the Attribute Window and then select the layer. So much easier now for the users! Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. Glad it is working for you. And please don't forget to mark the question as answered so it doesn't show up in the unanswered questions list.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! Just done that. Have a great weekend Dan.

Comment: I shall do my best. You do the same.